# Webpage downloads php file to browser instead of running it

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm setting up a simple login-page, however when I click on my "submit" button, instead of querying the MySQL database using a php file the browser downloads the php file.

I'm making this using Jetbrains Webstorm and am just using the "Run" shortcut to run the page.

Login Page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign-In</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sign-in">
        <fieldset style="width:30%"><legend>LOG-IN HERE</legend>
            <form method="POST" action="scripts/connectivity.php">
                Username<br><input type="text" name="user" size="40"><br>
                Password<br><input type="password" name="pass" size="40"><br>
                <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In">
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

connectivity.php

```php
<?php

    define('DB_HOST', 'REDACTED');
    define('DB_NAME', 'REDACTED');
    define('DB_USER', 'REDACTED');
    define('DB_PASS', 'REDACTED');

    $con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
    $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

    function SignIn() {
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST['user'])) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName WHERE userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])) {
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
            echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";
        } else {
            echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERED WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        SignIn();
    }
?>
```

I'm expecting that when I click the "submit" button it will tell me if that is an existing account or not. However upon clicking "submit", my browser downloads the connectivity.php file

Comment: Have you tried a simple "hello world" php script to test if your server has php?

Comment: Upon looking further, it appears that webstorm actually comments out any php code I have when it runs :/

Comment: Try another editor for your non-JavaScript files. You might also take a look to see if there is a configuration that would turn that behavior off. I haven't used WebStorm, so I can't offer any thing more detailed.

Comment: Okay :/ I made a really dumb mistake and saved it as a .html instead of a .php

Comment: We all do that kind of thing sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

I made a dumb mistake and saved it as a .html instead of a .php so the code wouldn't run.